# How to delete duplicate columns from csv file in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use nifi to convert csv files to json files. But I found the csv files have duplicate columns and I need to delete any repeated columns,
e.g.

COL1, Col2, Col3, COL1, Col4, Col5

How can I deal with these duplicate columns in NiFi?

Comment: I would say use `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor and put your cleaning logic in custom python script. It would be really easy with python & pandas to remove duplicate columns from dataframe.